# underlying functors

Tags: category-theory, forgetful-functors

Why in general the underlying (=forgetfull) functor $U$ preserves directed colimits but not all colimits.

Is there even a proof of this fact ?

Comment: The identity functor is it's own left/right adjoint, and preserves limits/colimits.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify what you mean by underlying functor, do you just mean right adjoint?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016618.

Comment: Just as a terminological note, all directed colimits are filtered, so the linked question also answers this one.